# SciTe and VS2012 Compiler

Tags: scite

Currently is seems like SciTe is trying to compile with g++ but I need it to compile with the vs compiler. how do I make it do this? its giving me this compiler error:

'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open **cpp.properties** file (Menu > Options > Open cpp.properties) then change `command.compile.$(file.patterns.cplusplus)` property to match your environment, which is set to gcc/g++ by default.

Comment: ok thanks, i think i was given a cpp.properties file that was to do that for me but im gonna go in and self edit it